# How to use an external program as a resource in c/c++ as one program

Tags: c++, c, windows

Say i have a program zip.exe which compresses a folder on the commandline as follows:

```
c:\zip.exe folder folder.zip
```

It creates a file folder.zip

Is it possible to complie zip.exe as a function in c\c++ as one program instead of something like:

```
system("c:\zip.exe folder folder.zip");
```

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: There are plenty of libraries that can be included into your c program, and will be able to create compressed zip files. In general most programs do not bundle executables into themselves(though it is possible). This question is likely to broad for stackoverflow. Try to identify a specific problem you need to solve and ask again

Comment: What you need is a compression library.

Comment: @rici this functionality allows you to execute exe from memory, so you can store exe as bytearray inside of your application and use it

Comment: @ilya: hmm, ok.

Comment: You need a library that can do it and include it in your program. Search for `lib`+whatever you want, for example `libzip`.

Comment: There are endless zip DLL's.....

Comment: @IłyaBursov This is was i was look for. thank mate.